# How to use array of distributions as argument for new distribution in pymc3

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm trying to model following problem:

- Before some switching point in time (chosen from DiscreteUniform distribution), values are chosen from Uniform distribution with bounds `early_low`, `early_high`. After this switch in time, values are chosen from Uniform distribution with bounds `late_low`, `late_high`. Given list of samples, estimate switching point and four bounds.

I would like to do something like this:

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model() as value_model:
        early_low = pm.Uniform("early_low", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        late_low = pm.Uniform("late_low", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        early_high = pm.Uniform("early_high", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        late_high = pm.Uniform("late_high", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        switch_date = pm.DiscreteUniform('switch_date', lower=date.min(), upper=date.max())
        low = pm.math.switch(date >= switch_date, late_low, early_low)
        high = pm.math.switch(date >= switch_date, late_high, early_high)
        measurements = pm.Uniform("measurements", low, high, observed=value)
```

Problem is, that I can't use `low` and `high` as parameters of `Uniform` distribution (see `measurements =`...). It is possible to use such arguments with Poisson distribution (of course there is only one argument). (See code in [Coal mining disasters](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html).) I don't know why.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357081/2727064) post, you can use arrays consisting of constants as parameters of distributions. I would like to use `low` and `high` in similar way.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314916/how-do-i-get-parameters-from-a-posterior-distribution-in-pymc) question shows creating deterministic function, but I'm not sure if this is somehow applicable to arrays.

Lastly, I thought about using mixture, something like this:

```
with pm.Model() as value_model:
        early_low = pm.Uniform("early_low", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        late_low = pm.Uniform("late_low", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        early_high = pm.Uniform("early_high", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        late_high = pm.Uniform("late_high", lower=value.min(), upper=value.max())
        switch_date = pm.DiscreteUniform('switch_date', lower=date.min(), upper=date.max())
        early = pm.Uniform("early", early_low, early_high, observed=value)
        late = pm.Uniform("late", late_low, late_high, observed=value)
        measurements = pm.Mixture("measurements", [date >= switch_date, date < switch_date], [late, early])
```

However this doesn't seem like way to go.

This is how I sample this model:

```
with value_model:
    trace = pm.sample(10000)
```

In ideal case, I'm looking for way to do something like `switch`, but instead of taking fixed values, it should decide between two distributions.

Comment: What happens when you use `low` and `high` for measurements?  I get that the model is misspecified.  What is happening is that there is no reason `early_low < early_high`, which leads you to regions with 0 probability.  Even after you fix that, `measurements` being uniform means you must be sure that the generative model never allows values outside the observed ones (as it stands, you *do* allow that).

Comment: You really should avoid `tt.switch` - it breaks down the nice geometry of your model and makes using NUTS to sample very difficult. You should try to rewrite your model into a continuous one, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144144